# Custom translator - The quality of the translation has significantly degraded

Tags: microsoft-translator

I have been using a Custom translator for 3 years — the task I'm doing: translating program code from Russian to English.
Every year I train a new model for translation, as my data for training the model is supplemented and extended.

Last week I trained another translator model and faced the following problems:

1. Training duration. The training took 1 day and 4 hours. Last year the model was trained in 4 hours. (The amount of data to train increased by about 10%.)
2. Quality of translation. The **BLEU score** came out to be **62.06** (baseline BLEU 16.98). Last year, the translation model got a **BLEU of 96.19** (baseline BLEU 23.34) on the same test dataset.

In fact, many of the translations produced by the model contradict the data used in training.

My questions:

- What could the degradation in translation quality be related to?
- Is it now possible to choose the previous year's version of the Custom translator for training?

Comment: Hi. Please reach out to translator@microsoft.com with your workspace id and project id and we would be happy to help debug the problem.